# How to add module aliases to Jest testing in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, next.js

Currently I am using automatic imports in my Next.js project, configured by `jsconfig.json` in the root directory:

```json
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": ["jest"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/functions/*": ["functions/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

When I add jest testing in a `test` directory at the root, the tests are not pointing towards the root directory. I have tried:

- adding a `jest.config.js` file that points to the root directory
- appending `typeAcquisition` to the `jsconfig.js`
- adding a `jsconfig.js` to the `tests` directory.

I am not sure which is the right path, or how to properly set this up, but none of these seem to work for me.  I can get the tests to run by removing the imports altogether and instead just `../../`-ing my way through the directory, but this requires me to change all the nested files as well
- i.e.: In `pages/api/budget`, I call a handler to go to `functions/api/fetchBudget`. In order for the Jest testing to reach it, I have to change the import statements on both of these to use the standard `../../` syntax, instead of `@pages/..` or `@functions` that I have set up.

**TL;DR:** How do I set up Jest testing to go through my project's root directory `jsconfig.json`; or, in lieu of that, how can I set up Jest testing with it's own `jsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend adding `ts-jest` in your project (npm i -D ts-jest) . After that, the `pathsToModuleNameMapper` function should be implemented to inject your paths from `tsconfig` into your `jest.config` settings:

```
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require("ts-jest");
const { compilerOptions } = require("./tsconfig");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({  
  dir: "./",
});

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to configure Jest to resolve the imports to match the paths you have in the `jsconfig.json` file. This is done through the `moduleNameMapper` property in your `jest.config.js` file.

```js
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
        '^@/functions/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/functions/$1',
        '^@/styles/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/styles/$1',
        '^@/pages/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages/$1'
    },
    // Other configs
}
```

---

For more details check out the [Next.js Testing](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#setting-up-jest-with-babel) docs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I wanted to automatically add the same nickname as defined in tsconfig.json, not to add again in jest config.

I added `"@components/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",` to `jest.config.js` and its worked, but it's not right solution,

Answer (score 1):

As the answers above mentioned, adding the following does indeed fix the `Cannot find module` issues:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
}
```

But what tripped me up was that adding the property to a new `jest.config.js` file didn't work as the project already had the jest config written in the `package.json` under the `jest` property:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
}
```

This `package.json` config was being used instead of `jest.config.js`, so you may need to update there instead.