# cannot import module when run jest test on next js app

Tags: typescript, jestjs, next.js

im newbie to typescript. trying to add some tests for a next app but ran into issues that i cant understand.

Here's my jest.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/.next/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    '^@models/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/models/$1',
    '^@controllers/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/controllers/$1',
    '^@middleware/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/middleware/$1',
    '^@mycomponents/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
  },
  moduleDirectories: [
    'src',
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
```

jest.setup.ts

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import ReactAdapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";

configure({ adapter: new ReactAdapter() });
```

the issue i run into is module not found ... src/@types/xxx

the test file is src/model/xxx

If i change the import from src/@types/xxx to ../@types/xxx than it works.

What did I do wrong? Note, there's one time the moduledirectories would resolve this issue but ht create another issue that can't find node_modules.

Thanks.

Comment: You should add a new entry in `moduleNameMapper` to handle `src/@types` imports just like you did for the other path aliases, e.g. `'^src/@types/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/@types/$1'`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`pathsToModuleNameMapper`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/) from `ts-jest` to automatically sync the path aliases defined in your `tsconfig.json` to the `moduleNameMapper`. See [How to add module aliases to Jest testing in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72128290/1870780).